# Why top and left border are not seen as single line?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.one {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
.two {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

In a DOM tree, `.two` div is a child of `.one` div. This parent-child relation has nothing to do with display of two elements.

As per the below diagram, I do not see the top and left border as single line. Why is the smaller box closer to center of the screen?

[image]

*Note: In computer graphics world, left-top corner of display is center of screen. html/css beginner*

Comment: "This parent-child relation has nothing to do with display of two elements." Yes it does. See the [box model](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/box.html). Div two goes in the content box of div one (but overflows)

Comment: @Alohci From the output, it does not look like div two goes in content box of div one.From DOM tree perspective, yes, Div two goes in the content box of div one. This [code](http://jsfiddle.net/drn2g6rr/1/) gives the output which is in alignment with the hierarchy(`p` is child of `div`)

Comment: Yes, because div two overflows div one to the right and below.

Comment: @Alohci When you write the code, How can one predict whether hierarchy is in alignment with display? For example,  [code1](http://jsfiddle.net/drn2g6rr/1/) output says that, DOM hierarchy is in alignment with display unlike above code output(in query), which is not intuitive. It is hard to imagine that the output looks like(as above) until you run the code. For me, output(in query) is not intuitive. This makes things harder to learn. I guess, your above comments are after seeing the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two lines are not joined together, because the `.two` element is **inside** the `.one` element.

You can see a div with a border as a room with a wall around it, which in this case contains another room with a wall around it. What you seemed to have expected to happen, was for the two 'rooms' to be placed **on top** of each other, while in HTML/CSS, the 'rooms' are placed **inside** each other. If you want the lines to join, you can use negative margins on the `.two` element like so:

```
.two {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```

This way, the `.two` element will look like it's placed on top of the other element

Comment: I have a question. Would you be able to answer(the same), without seeing the output of the code given in query?

Comment: Could you reformulate that? I don't know what you mean with 'query'

Comment: In that case yes. I would be able to answer what I've just answered without the output. Why do you want to know?

Comment: You mean, without running the code, you would know that output is going to be(as above), where div two would slide right&below div one. What logic would you apply to think of such output?

Comment: As you can read in my answer, HTML/CSS works that way. When you nest an element inside a parent, and give that parent a border, It will be built as a wall around it and thus forcing the child more to the right and bottom

Comment: Do you mean, if border is not given, child does not move to right&below?

Comment: Exactly. The same goes for padding

Comment: Upon inspection, the behaviour is same after removing the border. two div is in same position.

Comment: div.two has moved one pixel up, and one pixel left after you remove the border

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 questions here :

> Why isn't there a single line for top and left border ?

Because css is built that way, if you want a single line, you have to use only border-right and border-bottom for your inner div. (Or set border-top and border-left to 0)

> Why is the smaller box to center of the screen ?

EDIT about your EDIT : Because `.one` contains `.two` but there is no border fusion in css. So your big div is "inside" your small div, but is overflowing.

If you don't understand, maybe try to use different colors to differentiate your divs

Comment: Am not sure, I understand this answer. If `.two` div is bigger than `.one`, then how does it matter that `.one` div will be closer to center of screen?

Answer (score -1):

```
use this :

<div id="d1">
     <div id="d2">
 </div>
</div>




#d1{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}

#d2{
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
   border-color:red;
   border-width:1px;
   border-style:solid;
   position:relative;
    top:-1px;
   left:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Please dont teach me css layout/positioning/etc... Assume am one day old in html/css